# Atomic Absorption Spectrophotometer

Tags: instrument

What are the advantages and dis-advantages of single beam V/S double beam Atomic Absorption Spectrophotometer?
I am having a basics  knowledge of Atomic Absorption Spectrophotometer but when purchasing what elements should be considered?